# Present continuous or present simple with a passive form?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-tense

I´m having some trouble with the following sentence:

"Foundations like the Siemens Foundation, Bertelsmann Foundation, Robert Bosch Foundation and Telekom Foundation are strongly participating in the update of the schools in Germany and Berlin."

These companies are participating, but it could also be presented as a fact - they participate. First, I was gonna write they are involved but that would be a simple present passive form wouldn´t it? The more I think about this sentence, the more confused I get. Does anyone know which tense and verb form would be best?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[This would probably be a comment, if I had enough points to comment.]

The phrase "are strongly participating in the update of the schools" is just not idiomatic English.  It sounds like a translation. Modifiers and their referents have a relationship like food and wine.  Some go together, some don't. "Strongly" pairs with verbs of focused action: One exercises vigorously but pulls strongly. "Participate" is too unfocused a word to use with "strongly."

That said, because "participate" in this context implies continuing action, the progressive form of the verb is not necessary to distinguish an ongoing process from a one-time act. Something like "actively participate in modernizing the schools ..." should cover the ground.